# Visual Studio 2015 C# -- How to make open curly brace not insert space?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, curly-braces

When typing a function like the following:

```
public bool doSomething()
```

With the cursor at the end of the line, if I insert a `{` character, Visual Studio types `{`, inserting an extra space before the brace. I don't want the extra space. This does not appear to be an option in `Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Spacing`. If I `Ctrl+z` it removes the space, so it knows it's a separate operation. I've turned off all auto-format options and it's still auto-formatting. How do I make it stop trying to be smarter than me?

Edit: I've also just discovered that when I use the keyboard shortcut to uncomment a block of code, it adds that space back in. This is also a problem.